# Area under a curve with polar coordinates. Seems to be too simple?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Curve is given by equation:

$$r^2 = 2a^2|\cos \phi|$$

I would like to use the formula:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b (f(\phi))^2 \, d\phi$$

So, since equation is already squared, i can put the right side of it directly into formula.
Also, because there is absolute value of $\cos \phi$, the equation is correct for every $\phi$ in $[0;2\pi]$. So it comes to:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}2a^2|\cos \phi| \, d \phi$$

$$A = a^2\int_0^{2\pi} |\cos \phi| \, d \phi = 4a^2$$

Question is: is my way of solution correct? It seems to be too simple, and I have feeling like I didn't notice something. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: [See the polar plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%5E2+%3D+2+%7Ccos+%28theta%29%7C).  As it turns out, it would seem that your method happened to work.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of calculating the area in wolfram? And what does division of the plot on two parts (blue and violet) mean?

Comment: The graph is taken from $0$ to $\pi$.  The red is $+\sqrt{\,}$, the blue is $-\sqrt{\,}$.